# Expose float2/vector2 property from shader to Unity material inspector

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl, shaderlab

In a Unity shaderlab shader you can expose shader properties to the material inspector in the editor. This can be done by placing the properties you want to expose in the `Properties` section like so

```
Properties
{
    _SomeFloat("A Float", float) = 5
}
```

Unity defines a list of properties in the [documentation here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-Properties.html).

However this does not include any form of float2 or vector2, just single `Float` or `Vector` which consists of `xyzw`.

I tried setting the property type to `float2` And Vector2

```
_SomeFloat("A Float", float2) = (5,5)
_SomeFloat2("A Float2", Vector2) = (5,5)
```

which both return the error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected TVAL_ID at line 7`

or trying to cut down the `Vector` in half by setting only half the members

```
_SomeFloat("A Float", Vector) = (5,5)
```

which return the error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ','`

I could just use the Vector type and only use its `xy`, but that makes for unclear UI as there are now two unused elements in the inspector, and could not find a Property Attribute or Drawer (Such as `HideInInspector`) that allows you to hide the `zw` values from the inspector.

So is there a way to expose a float2 using a property type? Or maybe an alternative where you can place two float properties next to each other in the editor like Tiling/Offset drawer is in the standard `2D` property type (Maybe something similar to `[EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal][2]`)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From quick search I've found there's `MaterialPropertyDrawer` that can be extended to add custom tags in shader inspectors (ref: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MaterialPropertyDrawer.html).

Thus, you could use `Vector` property in shader, create custom attribute, let's say, `[ShowAsVector2]` and make `MaterialPropertyDrawer` for it, which would only show two input fields, and assign their value to vector's `x` and `y` values. This would result in shader property written as:

`[ShowAsVector2] _Position2D("Position", Vector) = (0, 0, 0, 0)`

Comment: Excelent! Wonder how I've not come across MaterialPropertyDrawer, for my reference what were your search terms?

Comment: "property drawer for shaders unity" - the first result was the reference I gave. Glad it helped! 

Answer (score 8):

This is an extension to [@tsvedas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60899673/6805333).

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;


/// <summary>
/// Draws a vector2 field for vector properties.
/// Usage: [ShowAsVector2] _Vector2("Vector 2", Vector) = (0,0,0,0)
/// </summary>
public class ShowAsVector2Drawer : MaterialPropertyDrawer
{
    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, MaterialProperty prop, GUIContent label, MaterialEditor editor)
    {
        if( prop.type == MaterialProperty.PropType.Vector )
        {
            EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth = 0f;
            EditorGUIUtility.fieldWidth = 0f;

            if (!EditorGUIUtility.wideMode)
            {
                EditorGUIUtility.wideMode = true;
                EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth = EditorGUIUtility.currentViewWidth - 212;
            }

            EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
            EditorGUI.showMixedValue = prop.hasMixedValue;
            Vector4 vec = EditorGUI.Vector2Field(position, label, prop.vectorValue);
            if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck()) {
                prop.vectorValue = vec;
            }
        }
        else
            editor.DefaultShaderProperty( prop, label.text );

    }
}
```

Simply put this script in an **[Editor](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpecialFolders.html)** folder, and you should be able to only see the `x` and `y` coordinates.